# First value in combobox have to be blank

Tags: php, html, combobox

I want the first and only first value in combobox to be empty. This is code:

```
while($rowTeams = mysql_fetch_array($resultTeams))
{
    echo '<option value="'.$rowTeams['home'].'">'.$rowTeams['home'].'</option>';        
}
```

I tried:

```
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
```

It's not a solution, because it makes a empty option every time it goes through loop. Any sugestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
echo '<option value=""></option>';
while($rowTeams = mysql_fetch_array($resultTeams))
{
    echo '<option value="'.$rowTeams['home'].'">'.$rowTeams['home'].'</option>';        
}
```